# Call control enter event upon re-entry

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm that uses multiple ListBox as well as TextBox Controls.  I have the tab order set up so the user can tab through the controls in sequential order.  I also wrote a function to check for empty and or unselected controls, forcing the user to fill out the form in it's entirety and therefore want all control Values blank until the user tabs to that control and or types a value to ensure the control wasn't over looked.

I  have ListBox(n).Listindex defualt to 0 upon the Control_Enter Event rather than -1.  This allows the user to tab into the control and key down the list rather smoothly. This Works on the first entry with the following code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Enter()
Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Upon submitting the form data, i.e. CommandButton1_Click(), The data is placed into a worksheet, all Control values are cleared and Focus is placed back on the first control in the form.  However, when the ListBox Controls are tabbed into, ListIdex defaults back to -1.  Why doesn't the Control_Enter event get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

The `Control_Enter` event occurs just before the control gets focus, for example by tabbing onto the control. However it will not occur again until the user exits that control. If you wish to handle a kind of *re-enter* event then you'd need programmatically to exit the control. I believe setting focus on another control would do it, eg `CommandButton1.SetFocus`.

However, I can't help thinking the user's interface experience would be odd. Changing a control when the user selects it, might cause the user to interpret his interface actions wrongly or as if the app was out of his control.

I'm struggling to see why you wouldn't set the `ListBox` values when the app launches and then whenever you process his selections. Presumably there is some code which handles the `ListBox` values, perhaps even triggered by some kind of *Execute* `CommandButton`. I'd reset the default values at the end of that code. This way there'd be a cue to the user that his selections had been successfully processed.

Comment: I have edited the question in an attempt to clearify what it is I'm trying to achieve.  I have used Control.SetFocus with no luck.  I also want to keep the ListBox values clear until the user tab's into the control so that i know the user has visited every field within the form before submitting the data.